# getcontentpane method in JFrame class

Tags: java

What is the use of `getContentPane` method in `JFrame class`? I googled it but I cant find appropriate answer.

```
class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        // Set layout manager
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Create Swing component
         JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");

        // Add Swing components to content pane
        Container c = getContentPane();

        c.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me again!");
        add(button1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.append("Hello\n");
            }

        });
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.append("Hello\n");
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the use of getcontentpane method in JFrame class?

In this case none. Since Java 1.5 `add` has automatically added components to the `ContentPane` so

```
c.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

can be written as

```
add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER); // can drop BorderLayout.CENTER obviously
```

similar to how `button1` is handled

There are instances where it is still useful to get the `ContentPane`, such as

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

Comment: then why we have such method?What is its use. Please give me appropriate example.

Answer (score 0):

A container has several layers in it. You can think of a layer as a transparent film that overlays the container. In Java Swing, the layer that is used to hold objects is called the content pane. Objects are added to the content pane layer of the container.

The getContentPane() method retrieves the content pane layer so that you can add an object to it.

The content pane is an object created by the Java run time environment. You do not have to know the name of the content pane to use it.

`getContentPane()` returns a container to hold objects. You can add objects on the returned container instead of adding objects directly to the JFrame or JDialog.

Comment: i am not getting.when we add button through container in frame or without container, we are getting same result. Why?

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope you get it.

Comment: Because it returns the default content pane of the JFrame which follows the Border Layout. You could add anothet container like JPanel to the frame and add objects to it instead.

Comment: adding to the container returned by `getContentPane` is the same as adding to the JFrame directly.

Answer (score 0):

Getvontentpane() will return contentpane of the frame.
Contentpane is like a place where all components are added.